# mod_rewrite virtual directory to download

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is it possible to rewrite a virtual directory to a file-download? I tried many solutions, but nothing works for me...

Goal:

```
<domain>/vfolder
```

to

```
<domain>/storage/file.zip
```

Thanks for your help!

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this one?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^vfolder$ /storage/file.zip [L]
```

Comment: After adding "Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch", your rule works. Thanks!